# CoffeeScript editor plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, coffeescript

Here's the deal, I use Wro4j to handle the transpilation/'building' of .coffee files to .js ones.

Now I want to have a good editor plugin which supports CoffeeScript, and I don't want to install Aptana (I only need CoffeeScript, not Python, Ruby and all the other stuff it includes and doesn't let me choose not to install...).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried coffeescript-eclipse plugin?

https://github.com/adamschmideg/coffeescript-eclipse

Comment: excellent, it works OK as I can see for these few minutes. One thing though. It requires installation of Xtext, http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/#overview if you don't have it installed it won't complain, and if not installed it will make errors when trying to open a .coffee file.

Comment: This file let you install quickly https://raw.github.com/Nodeclipse/eclipse-node-ide/master/CoffeeScriptSet.p2f

Answer (score 0):

Besides CoffeScript-Eclipse: https://github.com/adamschmideg/coffeescript-eclipse (mentioned by BluesRockAddict), the other choices I know of are:

LiClipse: http://brainwy.github.io/liclipse/

Aptana Studio 3: http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3