# CoffeeScript Editor Plugin in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, coffeescript

I would like to use Eclipse Kepler for CoffeeScript Development. I would like to use the CoffeeScript Editor Plugin, but I cannot get it running under Kepler. 
Maybe it works in older versions (there is an old post [CoffeeScript editor plugin for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286364/coffeescript-editor-plugin-for-eclipse) that let me assume that) but currently it throws only

```
An internal error occurred during: "XtextReconcilerJob".
  start > length()
```

Does anyone know how to solve that, or what alternative I could use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you installed `XText` as mentioned in the old post comments?

Comment: Yes. That did'nt change anything unfortunatly. Does the plugin work for you with Kepler?

Comment: I also have this problem..

Comment: I switched to Idea and a CoffeeScript-Plugin. It's neither a perfect plugin, but it works ;-) I'm trying WebStorm for a few days now and it seems to have a much better CoffeeScript-Editor, but I don't have much experience with that yet . and its not free.

Comment: I recommend Sublime Text with CoffeeScript snippet plugins

Comment: FTR: Atom is pretty stable now days and has excellent CoffeeScript support baked in.

Comment: It is a known issue that hasn't been resolved yet: https://github.com/Nodeclipse/coffeescript-eclipse/issues/19